# Rcpp extending and export attributes

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

```
#include<RcppCommon.h>

class TimeSerie {
  protected:
    SEXP m_data;
  public:
    TimeSerie(SEXP);
  operator SEXP();
};

#include<Rcpp.h>


using namespace Rcpp;

TimeSerie::TimeSerie(SEXP data):
  m_data(data) {
    if (! Rf_inherits(data,"ts")) stop("Not a ts object");
  }

TimeSerie::operator SEXP(){
  return m_data;
}

TimeSerie ident_ts(TimeSerie x){
  return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP ident(SEXP X) {
  return ident_ts(X);
}
```

I'm trying to follow the intrusive Rcpp-extending.
The previous code works therefore c++ knows about the implicit conversions in both ways :

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("test.cpp")
ident(ts(1:10))
```

[image: timeserie]

```
ident("notcool")
```

[image: error]

However, I can't make it work with the Rcpp::Export on the TimeSerie to TimeSerie function directly.

```
#include<RcppCommon.h>

class TimeSerie {
  protected:
    SEXP m_data;
  public:
    TimeSerie(SEXP);
  operator SEXP();
};

#include<Rcpp.h>


using namespace Rcpp;

TimeSerie::TimeSerie(SEXP data):
  m_data(data) {
    if (! Rf_inherits(data,"ts")) stop("Not a ts object");
  }

TimeSerie::operator SEXP(){
  return m_data;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
TimeSerie ident_ts(TimeSerie x){
  return x;
}
```

[image: result]

How is it possible to make the class the more beautiful possible, ie actually sticking the Rcpp Attributes to my class, not to SEXP ? I'm not a C++ addict so please be forgiving ;)

Thanks

Comment: There is a [vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf) dedicated to the topic that comes with your copy of Rcpp, a number of other questions here on StackOverflow as well as other posts _e.g._ on the Rcpp Gallery.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel and thanks for your wonderful work. I've read that vignette and my example was merely thought to be a simple example about this one. I understand that you must see a lot of the same questions, so sorry for the bother about that. l'll check Rcpp Gallery and the other SO posts again. Then, my question is specific about the place of the Rcpp attribute (for the cleanness)

Comment: I've also seen these nice article on your website, https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/ . There's also an example of yours https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-as-and-wrap-example/ . Guess I'll work with these non-intrusive explicit specializations, but I'd like to have it the implicit intrusive way too

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have read about your package. I noticed that, in my case, that was the const TimeSerie needed for wrap that had a problem to be sent to a non-const SEXP. It can be changed with a const_cast specialisation. However, I feel pretty unsafe about that. In your FAQ, you say " with SEXP objects, the const declaration can be
circumvented as it is really a pointer to the underlying R object". But then why did you expect const for the wrap function ? Is there an special meaning of the keyword const within Rcpp ?

Comment: Not all possibly converters are implemented. RcppArmadillo has both variants so you can use that if const is very important to you.  As we try to write it is a little tricky as we are dealing with the hand we're dealt which contains a raw C pointer in the SEXP.